# Undo function to revert the reset contents macro

Tags: vba, excel, undo

I have a Active X control button on Sheet that will "reset contents" of Sheet.

I also, would like to add an other button called "Undo Button" that should revert the contents cleared using "Reset Contents". Is this possible?

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
Worksheets("DropSheet").Range("E7:E15").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Please Suggest

Comment: It takes creating snapshots of the worksheet before the change and then resetting the page with the snapshot.  You literally will copy the sheet before doing the change then if an undo is wanted you paste the sheet back.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you for your reply. you suggest to have a sheet reserved to store snapshot and use when clicked on Undo button. Correct? One question, does it not increase the size of spreadsheet?

Comment: It will increase the size since you are creating a backup of the sheet (by copying it, even if it has the same values). The process would be something like: when press reset button copy the target sheet and hide it, then clear the target sheet contents. When clicking undo delete the target sheet and then copy the hidden sheet. (then the hidden sheet can be also deleted)

Comment: @RCaetano Thank you. Let me try to work on it. But my concern the size of the Sheets. As these spreadsheets will be shared to other users, increase in size will cause issues. After coping from hidden sheet. do you advise to delete the backup contents?

Comment: if you don't mind cells format you could store their values into an array, thus not increasing worksheet size. Of course this works during the same VBA session

Comment: Yes, because you just restored the old values so there is no need to have 2 equal sheets. The trick here is to backup when reseting / deleting the backup when "undoing". The @user3598756 also suggest something interesting that you should check ;)

Comment: @user3598756 Looks interesting!! Do you have a function that does the purpose,please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that in your relevant ("DropSheet"?) worksheet there are:

- an ActiveX button named after "CommandButton21"
- an ActiveX button named after "UndoBtn"

place this code in that very same worksheet code pane:

```
Option Explicit

Dim lastValues As Variant '<-- worksheet scoped variable where to store "last" values in before CommandButton21 button clears them

Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
    With Range("E7:E15") '<--| reference your relevant range
        lastValues = .Value '<--| first, store its content in the worksheet scoped array variable
        .ClearContents '<--| then, clear its content
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub UndoBtn_Click()
    Range("E7:E15").Value = lastValues '<--| write'em back!
End Sub
```

Comment: @sady, did you get through it?

Comment: not work in my excel